# How can I center Text in stack?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a Stack that has two children. An Icon and a Text. The Icon is larger in height than the text, and dictates the height of the Stack. I would like the Text to center in the stack regardless of the size of the Icon.

```
Stack(
    children: [
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
        child: GestureDetector(
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
          onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(4), child: Icon(Icons.close)),
        ),
      ),
      Center(
        child: Text(
          widget.title,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

With this current layout, the Text always draws at the top center of the stack, regardless of how Large the icon is. How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Stack`'s `alignment: Alignment.center` to align the `children`.

> The default value for 'alignment' is AlignmentDirectional.topStart.

```dart
Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  children: [
    const Text(
      "widget.title",
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
      child: GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4), child: Icon(Icons.close)),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

More about [Stack widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

When using `Stack` widget you must use `Positioned` widget to position children. You may refer to below code, and keep in mind that `last` widget will `overlap` `previous` widget of `Stack's children`. Ex. 1st will be overlapped by 2nd

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Positioned(
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      top: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      child: GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        child:
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(4), child: Icon(Icons.close)),
      ),
    ),
    Center(
      child: Text(
        widget.title,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

[image]

Comment: I want to position to Text not the GestureDetector

Comment: Actually if you use Center widget it align center it's child to center of the Stack,so to center something you don't need to use Positioned.

Comment: you may check updated answer.